# My application won't run because I'm missing MSVCR90.dll, what can I do?

Tags: python, wxpython, runtime-error, py2exe, msvcr90.dll

I used the instructions [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/DistributingYourApplication) to create my application. I get this message every time I double click my application after creating it with py2exe:

```
The program can't start because MSVCR90.dll is missing from your computer...
```

I don't know how I'm suppose to get this file: MSVCR90.dll.

I know this question has been asked before but I'll be honest the answers have left me more confused and also I'm seeing different answers everywhere. Using the [py2exe tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step6) it says I need version 9.0.21022.8 of the MSVCR90.dll so I use the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29) they give me. I download and install it but now I don't know what to do next as it doesn't seem to do anything aside from making a mess of my c drive. I tried creating the application again but the problem doesn't go away. I looked up in my computer to see if I have MSVCR90.dll and it takes me to a weirdly named folder which contains three .dlls: msvcm90.dll, msvcp90.dll, msvcr90.dll.

I copied this msvcr90.dll (version: 9.0.30729.1) to the dist folder and ran the application but it still doesn't work as it says: `Runtime error ... R6034...`

I even changed setup.py to add this line:

`options = {"py2exe": { "dll_excludes": ["msvcr90.dll"]}}` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try (re)installing Visual C 2008 redistributable, which you can get from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

Comment: Hey, I will do that but can you tell me what I should do afterwards. Do I rerun python setup.py py2exe? Or is there an intermediate step involved?

Comment: So I reinstalled it but it didn't do anything as still gives me the same error. I'm using windows 7 btw.

Comment: You should've wrote the edit as the answer and accept it, so it closes the question @shn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it worked. I had to include the images from the toolbar of my program within the dist folder. Aside from that you also need to exclude msvcp90.dll in setup.py.